# Combining many matrices with different names in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have 141 matrices with the same dimensions, but with different names like:

```
mat_1, mat_55, mat_154, ...
```

I have their names in another matrix:

```
"mat_1" , "mat_55" , ...
```

And now I'm trying to combine all of them in a single matrix. Should I write the name of all of them manually in `rbind()`, or there is another way?

rbind(mat_1,mat_55,....)

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: I am using R, on windows8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mat_1 = matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)
mat_2 = matrix(11:20, ncol = 2)
mat_3 = matrix(21:30, ncol = 2)

names = c('mat_1','mat_2','mat_3')

x = lapply(lapply(names, as.symbol), eval)
do.call("rbind", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
do.call(rbind, mget(mat_names))
```

where `mat_names` is the name of you vector including matrix names.